# Number of members in the church

Tags: calculus

In 2000 the membership for The Church  reached 10,753,000 members.

In 1984 the membership for The Church  was 5,400,000 members.

Letting t = 0 represent the year 2000 and assuming the church membership continues to double about every 16 years, predict the church membership in year 2055.

If t=0 is to be for year 2000 then how are we supposed to use the data given for year 1984? Is it just to show that people have almost doubled in 16 years?

And we know easily find number of members till 2048 but how to find for year 2055? Should be use unitary method type of approach?

Comment: If it is to double every $16$ years, then it will (approximately) increase by a factor of $\sqrt[16]2$ for each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's doubling every 16 years, then the formula for the membership is:
\begin{equation}m(t) = m_0.2^{t/16}\end{equation}
where $m_0$ is the membership at $t=0$, $t$ is the time in years.

If you wanted to have $y$ (the year) instead of $t$ which is zeroed then simply put $t=(y-2000)$.